# Mercurial clone failure: cannot find \.hg

Tags: mercurial, clone, tortoisehg

I am new to Mercurial, just installed TortoiseHg on Windows XP, and I am trying to clone my (new) repo to a mapped network drive on our local linux server.  I succeeded in cloning to a local folder, but when I do something like:

```
hg clone -U Repo Y:\repo_clone
```

I get the error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified: Y:\repo_clone\.hg
```

Same error if I try to hg init on the server, and regardless of the clone address I use (e.g. \\linuxserver).  What is going on here?  The \.hg folder does exist in the original repo, and I do have permissions to that drive.  I could not find any similar issues out there, so maybe it is something to do with my local network?  Any thoughts are appreciated!

Here's the traceback on hg init:

```
Y:\>hg init --debug --traceback Y:\Repo_clone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 87, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 684, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 466, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 738, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 692, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 681, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 454, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 3659, in init
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 104, in peer
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 93, in repository
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 2098, in instance
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 50, in __init__
  File "mercurial\win32.pyo", line 450, in makedir
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Y:\\Repo_clone\\.hg'
abort: The system cannot find the file specified: Y:\Repo_clone\.hg
```

Comment: I tried this with my current environment and it works. Do you have write access to Y:\ including the permission to create a new folder?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the `DEST` option in `hg clone`, but the [documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#clone) says this:

> Only local paths and ssh:// URLs are supported as destinations. For ssh:// destinations, no working directory or .hg/hgrc will be created on the remote side.

Since Y:\ isn't actually a local drive, that could be the source of the problem. Have you tried logging into the server and running `hg init` or `hg clone` locally there?

Comment: That's what I thought at first: that the problem is Y:\ is not actually a local drive.  But there are examples of others successfully cloning to network drives, e.g. [this question about cloning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504573/whats-the-best-strategy-for-automatically-cloning-a-repo-to-a-network-drive) or somewhat related, [this question about moving repos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203424/can-i-move-my-mercurial-working-directory-to-another-location)  so I am not yet convinced that is the issue...

Comment: Thanks everyone, it turns out we had a server setting which disallowed filenames beginning with '.' (so '.hg' was not allowed).  This setting has been modified and now there's no problem with cloning.  Nothing to do with Mercurial!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out!